# myBatis 3 query from tables without relationship

Tags: mysql, mybatis, ibatis, spring-mybatis, mybatis-generator

I got `2 tables`:
Table `StatementDetails` with `columns`:

```
    private String detailId;

    private BigDecimal tranxlogid;

    private String statementId;
```

Table `transLog` with `columns`:

```
    private BigDecimal tranxlogid;

    private Date datetime;
```

Then in `StatementDetailsMapper.xml`, I got a query:

```
<sql id="Base_Column_List">
        DETAIL_ID, TRANXLOGID, STATEMENT_ID, STATEMENT_GEN,
        STATEMENT_RECON
    </sql>

    <select id="reconStmtDetails" resultMap="StmtTranxDetailsResult"
        parameterType="java.lang.String">
        select
        <include refid="Base_Column_List" />
        from STATEMENT_DETAILS STD, POST_TRANX PT
        where PT.TRANXLOGID=STD.TRANXLOGID
    </select>
```

As you see that tranxlogid is not mapped between 2 tables, it's just a field.
However, when I exe query, I got errors:

```
The error occurred while setting parameters
Cause: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined
```

It seems like `POST_TRANX PT` is invalid.

Any ideas. Thanks.

Comment: What is in <include refid="Base_Column_List" /> . it looks that there are a field in the list without a alias TRANXLOGID. put an alias in front of the field

Comment: Hi, I added the alias. Could you take a look on it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What @BerndBuffen said is true, the error states that you are probably getting a column that exists in both tables (at least `TRANXLOGID`) so Oracle doesn't know which one to use. So your MyBatis `Base_Column_List` should look like this:

```
<!-- since I don't know which column is from wich table I consider -->
<!-- it to be all from STD -->
<sql id="Base_Column_List">
    STD.DETAIL_ID, STD.TRANXLOGID, STD.STATEMENT_ID, STD.STATEMENT_GEN,
    STD.STATEMENT_RECON
</sql>
```

Comment: Thanks. I just figure it out and found the result. Good day :).